# Getting exponents in a method without using Math.pow()

Tags: java, eclipse, exponent

This was the problem I was given:

Create method lastDigit that is passed two positive integers. The first integer is the base and the second integer is the exponent. lastDigit will return the last digit of base^exponent.  You need to think before you write your code.  Hint: You do not need to actually find the product of base^exponent.

Then I need to use the method to find answer the questions below:

1) What is the last digit of 3^400? 
2) What is the last digit of (3^0)(3^1)(3^2)(3^3)…(3^10)? 
3) What is the last digit of the product of (3^0)(3^1)(3^2)…..(3^400)?

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
public static int lastDigit(int m, int n){
    int p=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        p=p*m;
    return p%10;
}
```

However when I was trying to find the answers to the questions, I keep getting -1 for both the first and third questions, and 1 for the second question. Is there something wrong with the code, or how can I get the right answer?

Comment: Overflow. Change `p=p*m` to `p=(p*m)%10`

Comment: If you'll think harder, you'll find a way to get the answer without multiplying anything (in constant time). Hint: write down first ten powers of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int variable is overflowing. Try changing `p=p*m` to `p=(p*m)%10`.

Answer (score 2):

You or a program you wrote may be suffering from Integer Overflow.

This is caused by chronic limitation of the `int` type.

Symptoms include

- Negative integers that are really supposed to be positive
- Small numbers that are supposed to be big

This condition can be controlled by ensuring that your `int` values don't exceed 2 billion.

If symptoms persist, see a debugger, or print out intermediate values.

*side effects may include frustration, throwing your computer out of a window, and/or deleting important system files.

But in all reality, let's say that you have a base of seven.

7=7

7*7=49

49*7=343

The last digit is 3.

However, if you, only take the last digit in between operations,

7*7 =49 -> 9

9*7 =63

The last digit is still three.

Doing this keeps the number well below the `int` limit.

This is actually what the `p=(p*m)%10;` solution is:

```
p=           (p*m)                                    %10      
  multiply the previous digit by the exponent      take the last digit
```

Comment: @Maria It's pretty much the same as the other answer, but I added the example.